# Trigger for update timestamp field

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I'm trying to create trigger, that updates my `lastmodified` field on insert/update. Here's my trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER timestamp_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON orders
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE timestamp_update;
```

and my procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION timestamp_update()
RETURNS TRIGGER 
AS
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE orders
    SET lastmodified = getdate()
    WHERE orderid = new.orderid
    RETURN new; 
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Unfortunately when I try to update some field, field isn't updated. Also when i create row, the lastmodified field isn't updated.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `update` in a trigger like this because it may lead to endless recursive loop.
If you want to modify inserted/updated row, just change the `new` record:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION timestamp_update()
RETURNS TRIGGER 
AS
$$
BEGIN
    NEW.lastmodified = now();
    RETURN new; 
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

The syntax `create or replace trigger` is incorrect.

```
CREATE TRIGGER timestamp_trigger 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON orders
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE timestamp_update();
```